# How should i write producer /consumer code in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 1 thread streaming data and a 2nd (the threadpool) processing the data. The data processing takes around 100ms so I use to second thread so not to hold up the 1st thread.

While the 2nd thread is processing the data the 1st thread adds the data to a dictionary cache then when the 2nd thread is finished it processes the cached values.

My questions is this how should be doing producer /consumer code in C#?

```
public delegate void OnValue(ulong value);

public class Runner
{
    public event OnValue OnValueEvent;
    private readonly IDictionary<string, ulong> _cache = new Dictionary<string, ulong>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _cachePublisherWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(true);

    public void Start()
    {
        for (ulong i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            DataStreamHandler(i.ToString(), i);
        }
    }

    private void DataStreamHandler(string id, ulong value)
    {
        _cache[id] = value;

        if (_cachePublisherWaitHandle.WaitOne(1))
        {
            IList<ulong> tempValues = new List<ulong>(_cache.Values);
            _cache.Clear();

            _cachePublisherWaitHandle.Reset();

            ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(delegate
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (ulong value1 in tempValues)
                        if (OnValueEvent != null)
                            OnValueEvent(value1);
                }
                finally
                {
                    _cachePublisherWaitHandle.Set();
                }
            }, null);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Buffered value: {0}.", value));
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Runner r = new Runner();
        r.OnValueEvent += delegate(ulong x)
                              {
                                  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Processed value: {0}.", x));
                                  Thread.Sleep(100);

                                  if(x == 499)
                                  {
                                      sw.Stop();
                                      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time: {0}.", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
                                  }
                              };
        r.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy12yx1f(VS.80).aspx) on MSDN about Synchronizing the Producer and Consumer.  There is also a good example on the [Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#%5FWait%5Fand%5FPulse) site.

Comment: The Albahari site is correct. Sadly, that MSDN article has an incorrect implemenation which can lead to a live-lock scenario in situation where you wnat more than one consumer.

Answer (score 4):

The best practice for setting up the producer-consumer pattern is to use the [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) class which is available in .NET 4.0 or as a separate download of the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) framework. The idea is that the producers will enqueue using the `Add` method and the consumers will dequeue using the `Take` method which blocks if the queue is empty. Like [SwDevMan81](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95573/swdevman81) pointed out the Albahari site has a really good writeup on how to make it work correctly if you want to go the manual route.