# Best way to transfer struct from one process to another?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I have one server process and some clients, the clients need to send to the server as many structures as possible, they will not wait for any answer, just send and send. In which way i can transfer next struct in that case:

```
typedef struct tagTDATA {
         BYTE c1;
         DWORD dw1;
         DWORD dw2;
         char ch[255];
} TDATA, *PTDATA;
```

Cant use Boost. The best way its Win API. And i don't need code solution just point me in right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use boost?

Comment: @Nawaz, maybe he doesn't want to include boost with this software as it might be closed source product or just doesn't want to include all of boost for 1 function that he could write another way?

Comment: Boost's license is pretty good to go with commercial software. Please see the license terms. But in my understanding by using Boost, may increase the memory footprint of your application.

Comment: @Jesus This isn’t how Boost works. Your characterisation is wrong on both counts.

Comment: @Konrad, well in that case he might just not want the overhead of using boost

Comment: @Jesus Ramos, second assumption is correct

Comment: @Yola, then (I'm not familiar with windows too much at least the API) maybe you can allocate a shared memory page and write data to that page instead (easily possible in linux, not sure about windows)

Comment: @Jesus Ramos, client need to send structure to the server process, and not wait for any answer and just send another data if want. Server read data and dont say anything in response, just read an read. Server also need to do some calculation and disk operation with every chunk of data, so if clients will send packets too quickly, some data may lost, its ok.

Comment: @David Heffernan, yes, now trying to do it with WM_COPYDATA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for an asynchronous IPC mechanism. Sockets are probably the easiest way to achieve this. Pipes would be another obvious alternative, and there are many higher level libraries available, but I think sockets sound like the best fit.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding you can solve this issue by implementing a shared queue. The pattern of your problem is more towards [Producer Consumer Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem)

You can also take these examples

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728068.aspx
- [How should i write producer /consumer code in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629035/how-should-i-write-producer-consumer-code-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Are the server and clients on different hosts? If so, why don't you take UDP and to methods to serialize your structure to send via network and the second one to get it back to structure? ...

Comment: I think that the networking is your way. easy and fast to implement.

Answer (score 0):

[`WM_COPYDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is specifically meant for transferring structs between processes. Check it out.

You mentioned pointers though - and no, you cannot expect pointers to work between processes. If you have variable-length arrays or pointers, it's probably necessary to serialize the data, for example with BSON or XML.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can use WM_COPYDATA async with PostMessage. Or did I get that wrong?

Comment: I believe you must use SendMessage. But once the server receives the data, it can dispatch to a worker if async processing is needed.

Comment: OK, so the server would collect incoming items in a queue and process them when it was ready. That would allow async I agree.

Answer (score -1):

ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory ought to be able to do the trick for you.

Comment: Will this approach work if the struct contains some *pointers*?

Comment: @Nawaz: Very unlikely- almost no interprocess code can share pointers.

Comment: I don't think that is the reason. Even within the process, these APIs should fail, because (I think) it cannot handle *internal* indirection if it has to read the *content* located at the region pointed to by the *pointers*.

Comment: `WriteProcessMemory` is really not a good form of IPC. There's no notification of the I/O, and there's a lot of clumsiness like how does the client know which address to write to? You'll need to use another form of IPC, which basically invalidates the point of `WriteProcessMemory`.